# Meteor - Why main.scss is loaded first?

Tags: meteor, load-order

I have a client folder containing a main.scss, and a folder called home with a home.scss inside of it:

```
|client(directory)
|----home(directory)
|--------home.scss
|----main.scss
```

I read in Meteor doc main.* are load before else files. But my home.scss is override by main.scss, as if main.scss is loaded after... why?

Comment: Just realized main.* are load last, not first...

Comment: Also, files in deeper directories are loaded first. Leave the headaches behind and use packages.

Comment: I don't really know how to use packages to control load order... any tutorial? What is the best practice to put my "layout files" that I call main.* ? In a LIB directory ?

Comment: Simply check [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Answer (score 0):

Because `main.scss` load last, and it's "Cascading Style", so the last styles always override the same (if you have) before.